# Bootstrap nav-tabs not clickable on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the bootstrap 3.3.7 nav-tabs' button. On desktop devices the buttons are working, but on mobile devices they are not clickable. Below please find the code.

```css
//nav tabs to have buttons work on mobile devices
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.List li').on('touchstart click ', function() {
        $('.Div').slideDown('500');
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 
  <head>
 <title>Agricultural Directorate</title>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
 
</head>
<body>

<div style="padding:25px;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTabs">
        <li style="cursor:pointer !important;" role="presentation" class="active settingshead">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#first">Testing</a>
        </li>
        <li style="cursor:pointer;" role="presentation" class="settingshead">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#second">Implementation</a>
        </li>
        <li style="cursor:pointer;" role="presentation" class="settingshead">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#third">Requirements</a>
        </li>
        <li style="cursor:pointer;" role="presentation" class="settingshead">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#fourth">Maintainance</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:40px;padding-right:40px;" class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="first">
        <div class="namedesig">
            <h4>Dr. Jane Doe</h4>
            <p>tester</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="second">
        <div class="namedesig">
            <h4>Dr. Martin</h4>
            <p>Implementer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="third">
        <div class="namedesig">
            <h4>Dr. John</h4>
            <p>Requirements</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="fourth">
        <div class="namedesig">
            <h4>Dr. Watson</h4>
            <p>Maint....</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Another detail, which maybe is important, is that the buttons are working when the website is opened on a mobile device through an Internet Explorer browser.

Comment: I had to stop using nav tabs and pills on my website. Last I read there was a known issue using these.

Answer (score 0):

These are working on mobile for me.

Open this on a mobile device:
https://codepen.io/mikeabeln_nwea/pen/WKoERK?editors=1010

The one change that I made is in the jQuery function, which may be causing the problem on some devices / mobile browsers:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.List li').on('click ', function() {
        $('.Div').slideDown('500');
    });
});
```

The `$('...').on('click')` handler manages desktop (mouse) click events as well as touch (tap) events on mobile devices, so the `touchstart` event binding is not necessary.

Binding `touchstart` might override that behavior and cause this problem, but without testing on the specific mobile device + browser that you're using I can't be sure.

Hope this is helpful...